# Permanent custom keymap

Tags: settings, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I use ElementaryOS on a chromebook. The keyboard top row has Xf86-like keys which are wrongly mapped as F keys by the hardware. Therefore I made a script to change the keymap at boot with Xmodmap. It works, but the keys are reset after seemingly random events. I suspect this is caused by the hotkey utility, which reload the layout for some reason.

How can I make these changes permanent?

[image]